# Best approach for casting pointer to method from derived to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointer-to-member

We have a base class ByteCode which is intended to be generic.
Children of ByteCode are expected to write methods of the form:

```
void m();
```

The ByteCode class should have a definition for method:

```
typedef void (ByteCode::*Method)();
```

In order to execute the bytecode, we have:

```
void exec() {
  while (true) {
    uint16_t opcode = getOpcode();
    Method m = opcodes[opcode];
    this->*m();
  }
}
```

Doing this in one class would be no problem.  But we have the generic code in the base class, and the derived has the array:

```
class MyByteCodeEngine : public ByteCode {
private:
  static Method opcodes[65536];

  void m1() {}
  void m2() {}
  void m3() {}
};

Method MyByteCodeEngine ::opcodes[65536] = {
  MyByteCodeEngine::m1,
  MyByteCodeEngine::m2,
  MyByteCodeEngine::m3
}
```

The problem is that these methods are not base class, they are derived. But the only instance we have is derived, We don't want to incur the overhead of virtual, we just want to cast and make this work, but the compiler is catching every trick. If it would just trust us:

```
Method MyByteCodeEngine ::opcodes[65536] = {
  (Method)MyByteCodeEngine::m1,
  (Method)MyByteCodeEngine::m2,
  (Method)MyByteCodeEngine::m3
}
```

We can solve this problem by eliminating the ByteCode class, but this forces us to repeat the code any time we have a bytecode interpreter. Any suggestions on how to fool C++ into accepting this, cleanly?

Comment: I'd use a `std::vector<std::function<void ()>>` and initialize these with lambdas capturing `this` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) so that the base class knows about the type of the member function.

```
template<class T>
struct ByteCode {
  typedef void (T::* Method)();

  void exec() {
    while (true) {
      uint16_t opcode = getOpcode();
      Method m = T::opcodes[opcode];
      static_cast<T*>(this)->*m();
    }
  }
};

class MyByteCodeEngine : public ByteCode<MyByteCodeEngine > {
  private:
    static Method opcodes[65536];

    void m1() {}
    void m2() {}
    void m3() {}
};

MyByteCodeEngine::Method MyByteCodeEngine ::opcodes[65536] = {
  &MyByteCodeEngine::m1,
  &MyByteCodeEngine::m2,
  &MyByteCodeEngine::m3
}
```

Comment: I also thought about that. I believe using the CRTP in combination with the proposal in my comment at the OP would be _the best_ and safest way to do this.

Comment: Definitely. This is what CRTP is for.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Dunno, `std::function` can be a little heavy. Although I believe common implementations have an optimisation for simple function pointers - not sure whether this also applies to pointers-to-member. The vector is another unnecessary dynamic allocation (though I'd consider `std::array`)

Comment: @Light Well, the overhead is a good argument against of course.

Comment: Looks decent enough as-is I'd say, although I wonder whether all 65536 are really needed; is it a sparse collection?

Comment: Also wonder whether the inheritance is actually needed at all. Just have a `ByteCodeExecuter<T>` ? But it could be the real `*ByteCodeEngine` types have other functions and stuff that warrant inheritance

Comment: I really like the last suggestion.  Why use inheritance at all? This is much better as a template.  But all the suggestions are interesting and instructive, so thanks!